# Why do I need manually tap 'Refresh' in Applozic Chat?

Tags: sdk, chat, messenger, applozic

I had run Applozic Sample chat from https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK, but it seems the sample doesn't provide real time synchronization within, it need manually refreshed to receive new messages. Anyone could help to make it synchronized in real time?

Comment: You changed the applicationkey in sample chat project or it is same?

Comment: @SunilKumar yes, I change it to my own applozic application key. I've also fill the GCM key from applozic dashboard setting

Comment: Your using FCM or GCM?

Comment: In our sample project we have setup for FCM ,if applicationKey is changed then You have to create the project in firebase console with same project package as a sample chat project and replace new google-services.json and then From cloud message tab you have get the legacy server and update that in  applozic dashboard

Comment: @SunilKumar Yeah, that's the problem. You can put that in answer section and i'll mark it as an answer. Thanks :D

Comment: @Sunil Kumar please can you explain me how to use real time chat and video audio calling with real time chat ui customization ??


i already implemented real time chat and audio video calling both but i am unable to update chat Ui because i added below dependency compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:4.78' And i am also tried with your sample github project but it is only for realtime chat and not support audio video calling please share sample if you have? Because i need to purchase this library

Comment: @Amit Desale we have two different sdk  1)one only for chat messaging without audio video calling github sample app link https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK and 2)chat messaging with audio video calling github sample app link https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-Chat-Sample/tree/master/Applozic-Android-AV-Sample  for complete doc you can check this link  https://www.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-sdk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Applozic sample chat project](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK)  we have setup for FCM, if applicationKey is changed then you have to create new project in [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) with same project package as a sample chat project and replace with new **google-services.json** and then from cloud messaging tab in firebase console you have get the legacy server and update that in  [Applozic](http://www.applozic.com) dashboard under edit action section in Push notification tab